# Can't select datepicker button using phpunit selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, phpunit

I am running phpunit with Selenium to test a website. I start Selenium Server with Chromedriver. I want to simulate a click on a datepicker calendar button. But, I cannot seem to get it working.  I have looked on the web and could not find any help.  Does anyone here have an idea?

```
$datepickerButton = $this->byXpath("//*[@id='42a1df47-59bf-445f-8641-02c453d0218c']/input"); // Select Datepicker button
$datepickerButton->click(); // Click $datepickerButton button
```

Thanks
Conor

==
HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

--

Comment: Can you provide a direct reference to the page, or an HTML snippet?

Comment: Hi @neet_jn, I will post the html and the xpath to click on the button